# How to cluster a mixed variable dataframe describing events?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, cluster-analysis, spacy

I have a HUGE dataframe containing features that describe events. Most of the columns in the dataframe contain string data, most of the time with more than one word per cell. There are 3 exceptions however, one where a column contains a full text with a more detailed description of the event, another column which contains a date, and another which contains and integer, representing money value. The challenge is to cluster the rows into events. As I do not know what the events are nor how many there are, I will have to use an unsupervised clustering algorithm (I was suggested to use KMedoids). Disregarding the topic of data preprocessing which is obvious, I am facing 2 challenges: how can I cluster string data when having more than one word in a single cell? how can I cluster when having mixed data types such as strings, dates, and integers? I've done some research and I am well aware that I have to vectorize the words using word2vec and akin, but I am just not sure how to use these vectors when having more than one word per cell. Should I average the vectors per cell and use that as an input for my clustering algorithm? Then how do I cluster vectors and integers or floats? 
We can pretend that my data looks like this:

```
Location   |   Date       |          Description       | Cost  |  Activity        | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Japan      | 30.11.2005   | ate an ice cream, was fun  | 1.3   |eating food       |  
USA        | 23.06.2012   |went to the beach and ocean | 20.5  |visit places      |
Columbia   | 19.12.2017   | went biking and ate candies| 4.8   |slept and ate     |
Russia     | 08.05.2003   | I forgot what we did, fun  | 90.8  |lazy sleep        |
...
Idia       | 08.07.2018   |there was an accident street| 100.8 | paid money       |  
Germany    | 08.04.2004   | ate an ice cream, was fun  | 1.3   |money             |  
France     | 08.02.2013   | ate an ice cream, was fun  | 1.3   |eat               |
```

Comment: You can start with bag of words first.

Comment: @VivekKumar, I actually did that. Do you think that I should consider a document an entire row?